Computing integral using complex analysis $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(\sinh(x)-i)}dx$
I couldn't find related problem, so here I am.

I have this integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh(x)-i}dx=I
$$
that i need to compute using complex analysis.
I am given the answer is $\pi$, and I need to use a rectangular contour connecting the points
$-R, R, R + i\pi$ and $-R + i\pi$.
I successfully proved, that integrals over vertical lines are approaching zero as R approach infinity, and calculated integral over the top horizontal line as
$$
I+i\pi\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{\sinh(x)-i}dx
$$
Then, when calculating residue inside the contour, I noticed that the poles are second order and looks like $z=i\pi/2+k\pi$.
Calculating residue relied on using l'Hospital rule four times and finally got the value of $-2i$ in the $z_0=i\pi/2$.
But then when putting everything back to the equation:
\begin{align}
& \int_\Gamma\frac{z}{(\sinh(z)-i)}dz
\\[5mm] = & \ \int_{-R}^R\frac{x}{(\sinh(x)-i)}dx+\int_{-R}^R\frac{x}{(\sinh(x)-i)}dx+i\pi\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{\sinh(x)-i}dx
\\[5mm] = & \ 2\pi i(-2i)
\end{align}
I get that
$\displaystyle
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(\sinh(x)-i)}dx=2\pi$,
when comparing the imaginary and real part. What am I missing ?.


But $\sinh (x+i\pi) =  - \sinh (x)$. So what you would have got then is: $\int_\Gamma \frac{z}{\sinh (z) - i} dz = \int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh (x) - i} dx - \int_{-R}^R \frac{x+i \pi}{-\sinh (x) - i} dx$. And I think the poles should be at $z = i\pi/2 + i k 2 \pi$.
Are you sure the rectangle shouldn't be $-R, R, R+i2\pi$, and $-R+i2 \pi$? Because I think I have a way of obtaining the integral in that case.

You are right about that integral, and unfortunately, I got these coordinates provided.

If $I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh x -i} dx$. Making the substitution $y=-x$ results in $I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y}{\sinh y +i} dy$. So that $I=I^$. Then $\int_\Gamma \frac{z}{\sinh z - i}dz = 2 I + i \pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh x + i}dx = 2I + i \pi J$. However, you have to be careful because the integral $J = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh x + i}dx$ is not real! Making the substitution $y=-x$ results in $J= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh y - i} dy$. Implying $J=-J^$. Can you then calculate $J$ from $\int_\Gamma \frac{dz}{\sinh z - i}$?

I managed to calculate $J$ by moving up the upper bound of the rectangle to $2i\pi$, so that making the same steps results in vanishing of $I$ integral. I was stuck on that, but thank you that you pointed out $I=I*$!

Another way of seeing $I=I^$ is to note $I-I^ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh x-i}dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh x+i}dx = 2 i \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh^2 x+1}dx = 0$ where the end integral vanishes because you are integrating an odd function.

We have:
\begin{align*}
\int_\Gamma \frac{z}{\sinh (z) - i} dz & = \int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh (x) - i} dx + \int_R^{-R} \frac{(x+ i \pi)}{- \sinh (x) - i} dx
\nonumber \\
& = \int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh (x) - i} dx + \int_{-R}^R \frac{x}{\sinh (x) + i} dx + i \pi \int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{\sinh (x) + i} dx
\nonumber \\
& = I + I^* + i \pi J
\end{align*}
Note when we integrate along the top of the rectangle we integrate from $R$ to $-R$: $\int_R^{-R} \cdots dx$, which is equal to $-\int_{-R}^R \cdots dx$.
Making the substitution $y=-x$ into $I$ results in
\begin{align*}
I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y}{\sinh y +i} dy 
\end{align*}
So that $I=I^*$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_\Gamma \frac{z}{\sinh (z) - i} dz  = 2I + i \pi J  \qquad (1)
\end{align*}
The integral $J$ is easy to perform. First note that $\frac{1}{\sinh (x) + i} = \frac{2 e^x}{(e^x+i)^2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
J = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh x +i} dx & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
 \frac{2 e^x}{(e^x+i)^2} dx
\nonumber \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty -\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{2}{e^x+i} \right) dx
\nonumber \\
& = \left[ - \frac{2}{e^x+i} \right]_{-\infty}^\infty = - 2i .
\end{align*}
Calculating residues:
Instead of using l'Hospital rule four times, it may be easier to expand:
Note $\frac{z}{\sinh (z) - i} = \frac{2 e^z z}{(e^z-i)^2}$. We expand in powers of $z-z_0$ about the pole $z_0 = i \pi /2$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2e^z z}{(e^z-e^{z_0})^2} & = \frac{2e^z z}{(e^{z_0+(z-z_0)}-e^{z_0})^2}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-2 z_0} \frac{2e^z z}{(e^{(z-z_0)}-1)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-2 z_0} \frac{2e^z z}{[(z-z_0)+ \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0)^2 + \cdots]^2}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-2 z_0} \frac{2e^z z}{ (z-z_0)^2 [1+ \frac{1}{2} (z-z_0) + \cdots]^2}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-2 z_0} \frac{2e^z z}{ (z-z_0)^2} [1 - (z-z_0) + \cdots]
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-2 z_0} \frac{2e^{z_0+(z-z_0)} [z_0+(z-z_0)]}{ (z-z_0)^2} [1 - (z-z_0) + \cdots]
\nonumber \\
& = e^{- z_0} \frac{2[1 + (z-z_0) + \cdots ][z_0 + (z-z_0)]}{ (z-z_0)^2} [1 - (z-z_0) + \cdots]
\nonumber \\
& = e^{- z_0} \frac{2z_0}{(z-z_0)^2} + e^{- z_0} \frac{2}{z-z_0} +\cdots
\end{align*}
So the residue at $z_0= i \pi /2 $ is:
\begin{align*}
Res_{z= i \pi/2} \left[ \frac{z}{\sinh (z) - i} \right] = - 2i  .
\end{align*}
Substituting in residues into $(1)$:
Substituting this residue and $J= - 2 i$ into $(1)$:
\begin{align*}
2 \pi i (-2i) = 2I + i \pi (-2i)
\end{align*}
Rearranged gives
\begin{align*}
I = \pi  .
\end{align*}

I think it is not necessary to use residue method. In fact,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sinh(x)-i}dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x(\sinh(x)+i)}{\sinh^2(x)+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sinh(x)}{\cosh^2(x)}dx+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\cosh^2(x)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sinh(x)}{\cosh^2(x)}dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xd\bigg(\frac1{\cosh(x)}\bigg)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\cosh(x)}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{\cosh(x)}dx=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{e^x+e^{-x}}dx=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx\overset{e^x\to x}=4\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\pi.$$

Here is another complex contour integration method to add to your repertoire:
\begin{align*}
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y}{\sinh y - i} dy & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
 \frac{2 y e^y}{(e^y-i)^2} dy
\nonumber \\
& = \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \ln x}{(x-i)^2} dx
\end{align*}
where we have used $e^y=x$. In the following we will again use that $I=I^*$.
We take the branch cut to be along $(-\infty,0)$. If we restrict ourselves to $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ and $|z|> 0$ the logarithm function given by $\ln z = \ln |z| + i \theta$, where $z=|z| e^{i \theta}$, is single valued and analytic.
Consider the contour as shown in the figure and the contour integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(z-i)^2} dz
\end{align*}
To avoid the branch point at $z=0$, we integrate around a small semi-circle near the origin. Consequently, within the region enclosed by this contour, the integrand is analytic except at the pole $z=i$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(z-i)^2} dz & = \int_\epsilon^R \frac{\ln x}{(x-i)^2} dx + \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) dz + \int_R^\epsilon \frac{\ln x + i \pi}{(x+i)^2} (-dx) - \int_{\Gamma_\epsilon} f(z) dz
\nonumber \\
& = \int_\epsilon^R \frac{2 \ln x}{(x-i)^2} dx + i \pi \int_\epsilon^R \frac{1}{(x+i)^2} dx + \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) dz - \int_{\Gamma_\epsilon} f(z) dz  \qquad  (1)
\end{align*}
where $\int_R^\epsilon \frac{\ln x + i \pi}{(x+i)^2} (-dx)$ is the contribution to the path just above the cut.
We prove the last two integrals vanish in the respective limits $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. We make the estimate
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) dz \right| & \leq \int_0^\pi \left| \frac{\ln R + i \theta}{(R e^{i \theta} - i)^2} R i e^{i \theta} \right| d \theta
\nonumber \\
& \leq \int_0^\pi \frac{(\ln R + \pi) R}{(R-1)^2} d \theta
\end{align*}
This behaves as $R^{-1} \ln R$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and so vanishes in this limit. Next,
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{\Gamma_\epsilon} f(z) dz \right| & \leq \int_0^\pi \left| \frac{\ln \epsilon + i \theta}{(\epsilon e^{i \theta} - i)^2} \epsilon i e^{i \theta} \right| d \theta
\nonumber \\
& \leq \int_0^\pi \frac{(|\ln \epsilon| + \pi) \epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)^2} d \theta
\end{align*}
This behaves as $\epsilon \ln \epsilon$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and so vanishes in this limit.
Taking the limits $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ in equation $(1)$ and rearranging gives
\begin{align*}
I = \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \ln x}{(x-i)^2} dx & = \int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(z-i)^2} dz - i \pi \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+i)^2} dx 
\nonumber \\
& = \int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(z-i)^2} dz - i \pi \left[ - \frac{1}{x+i} \right]_0^\infty 
\nonumber \\
& = \int_\Gamma \frac{\ln z}{(z-i)^2} dz - \pi  .
\end{align*}
Calculate residues:
We expand in powers of $z-z_0$ around the pole $z_0 = i$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln z}{(z-z_0)^2} & = \frac{\ln [z_0 + (z-z_0)]}{(z-z_0)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\ln z_0 + \ln [1 + (z-z_0)/z_0]}{(z-z_0)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\ln z_0 + [(z-z_0)/z_0 - \cdots]}{(z-z_0)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\ln z_0}{(z-z_0)^2} + \frac{1/z_0}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
I & = \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \ln x}{(x-i)^2} du = (2 \pi i) (-i) - \pi = \pi  .
\end{align*}
